# NSUserAppleScriptTask returning large value never calls completionHandler

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I have an Objective-C app that is using NSUserAppleScriptTask to call some Applescript. The applescript is returning a string that can vary in size.

It works fine with the string is short. However, when it gets very long, it starts failing silently. If it attempts to return a string that is 40,000 characters long, the `completionHandler` will never be called, and the string `returned ...` is never printed. No messages to the log, no messages to the console. It is just never called.

A string of 30,000 characters works fine. I'm not sure where the precise cutoff is.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a property or configuration setting I could change to increase this limit? Or do I just need to give up on NSUserAppleScriptTask?

### Code

```
NSURL* scriptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ApplescriptHelper" withExtension:@"scpt"];
NSError* error;
NSUserAppleScriptTask* task = [[NSUserAppleScriptTask alloc] initWithURL:scriptURL error:&error];
NSLog(@"created task %@, error %@", task, error);

/* CREATE APPLE EVENT */
// taken from https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/
ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
NSAppleEventDescriptor *target = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithDescriptorType:typeProcessSerialNumber bytes:&psn length:sizeof(ProcessSerialNumber)];

NSAppleEventDescriptor *function = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithString:@"test"];

NSAppleEventDescriptor *event = [NSAppleEventDescriptor appleEventWithEventClass:kASAppleScriptSuite eventID:kASSubroutineEvent targetDescriptor:target returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
[event setParamDescriptor:function forKeyword:keyASSubroutineName];
/* END CREATE APPLE EVENT */

[task executeWithAppleEvent:event completionHandler:^(NSAppleEventDescriptor*resultEventDescriptor, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"returned %@, error %@", resultEventDescriptor, error);

    if (!resultEventDescriptor) {
        NSLog(@"%s AppleScript task error = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"success")
    }
}];
```

#### ApplescriptHelper.scpt

```
on test()
    set str to ""
    repeat 40000 times
        set str to str & "x"
    end repeat
    return str
end fetchMusic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an Apple bug. You should file a report.

Running your code, `osascript` stalls with the following call graph:

```
+ 2812 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff97a205b4]
+   2812 exit  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 55  [0x7fff9157f403]
+     2812 __cxa_finalize_ranges  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 345  [0x7fff9157f0ff]
+       2812 std::__1::ios_base::Init::~Init()  (in libc++.1.dylib) + 16  [0x7fff8f1ebd98]
+         2812 std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()  (in libc++.1.dylib) + 68  [0x7fff8f1e2f5a]
+           2812 std::__1::__stdoutbuf<char>::sync()  (in libc++.1.dylib) + 137  [0x7fff8f1ec30d]
+             2812 fflush  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 40  [0x7fff9155c31c]
+               2812 __sflush  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 87  [0x7fff9155c3c0]
+                 2812 _swrite  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 87  [0x7fff91563e96]
+                   2812 __write_nocancel  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff918e57ba]
```

I think you're running into the [pipe buffer limit of 65536 bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954).

If you play with the undocumented `osascript` arguments that `NSUserAppleScriptTask` uses, you get raw AppleEvent output with a 16-byte header & `UTF-16` encoded text.

Anything over `32760` in your `repeat` loop causes this behavior. `32760` * `2` + `16` = `65536`.

Comment: I submitted a bug report. Thanks for the detailed response. I'll update this if I hear from Apple.

Comment: It's 2018 and noticed the same thing, i want to get the git logs of an entire month. Did they say anything to your bug report?